# How to load a model using Tensorflow Hub and make a prediction?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-hub

This should be a simple task: Download a model saved in tensorflow_hub format, load using tensorflow_hub, and use..

This is the model I am trying to use (simCLR stored in Google Cloud): https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/simclr-checkpoints/simclrv2/pretrained/r50_1x_sk0;tab=objects?pageState=(%22StorageObjectListTable%22:(%22f%22:%22%255B%255D%22))&prefix=&forceOnObjectsSortingFiltering=false

I downloaded the /hub folder as they say, using

```
gsutil -m cp -r \
"gs://simclr-checkpoints/simclrv2/pretrained/r50_1x_sk0/hub" \
```

.

The /hub folder contains the files:

```
/saved_model.pb
/tfhub_module.pb
/variables/variables.index
/variables/variables.data-00000-of-00001
```

So far so good.
Now in python3, tensorflow2, tensorflow_hub 0.12 I run the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

path_to_hub = '/home/my_name/my_path/simclr/hub'

# Attempt 1
m = tf.keras.models.Sequential([hub.KerasLayer(path_to_hub, input_shape=(224,224,3))])

# Attempt 2

m = tf.keras.models.Sequential(hub.KerasLayer(hubmod))
m.build(input_shape=[None,224,224,3])


# Attempt 3

m = hub.KerasLayer(hub.load(hubmod))

# Toy Data Test

X = np.random.random((1,244,244,3)).astype(np.float32)

y = m.predict(X)
```

None of these 3 options to load the hub model work, with the following errors:

```
Attempt 1 :

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected keras_layer_2_input to have shape (224, 224, 3) but got array with shape (244, 244, 3)

Attempt 2:

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node sequential_3/keras_layer_3/StatefulPartitionedCall/base_model/conv2d/Conv2D}}]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_46402]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph

Attempt 3:

ValueError: Expected a string, got <tensorflow.python.training.tracking.tracking.AutoTrackable object at 0x7fa71c7a2dd0>
```

These 3 attempts are all code taken from tensorflow_hub tutorials and are repeated in other answers in stackoverflow, but none works, and I don't know how to continue from those error messages.

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Update 1:
Same issues happen if I try with this ResNet50 hub/
https://storage.cloud.google.com/simclr-gcs/checkpoints/ResNet50_1x.zip

Comment: It seems that the problem is your input shape. `224 != 244`.

Comment: @Frightera wow I took me a while to spot the difference. This was a major help, and was able to solve the other issues. Will spot the working code as an answer but maybe should delete the whole question overall.

Answer (score 0):

As @Frightera pointed out, there was an error with the input shapes. Also the error on "Attempt 2" was solved by allowing for memory growth on the selected GPU. "Attempt 3" still does not work, but at least there are two methods for loading and using a model saved in /hub format:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub   

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices(gpus[0], 'GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpus[0], True)


hubmod = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_035_96/feature_vector/5'

# Alternative 1 - Works!

m = tf.keras.models.Sequential([hub.KerasLayer(hubmod, input_shape=(96,96,3))])
print(m.summary())

# Alternative 2 - Works!

m = tf.keras.models.Sequential(hub.KerasLayer(hubmod))
m.build(input_shape=[None, 96,96,3])
print(m.summary())

# Alternative 3 - Doesnt work

#m = hub.KerasLayer(hub.load(hubmod))
#m.build(input_shape=[None, 96,96,3])
#print(m.summary())

# Test

X = np.random.random((1,96,96,3)).astype(np.float32)
y = m.predict(X)

print(y.shape)
```